# Accepting your own answer with alternative answers to be worth +2 reputation?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, self-answer

Today, when you accept an answer you did not provide, you get a +2 reputation, however, if you accept your own answer, you get +0.

I expect the reason for this is to stop people gaming the system by asking and answering their own questions repeatedly.

However, this has the downside of providing a disincentive of accepting your own answer when it seems the best and instead accepting an inferior one in order to get the reputation bonus.

Therefore, I propose that the accept your own answer is only worth zero when there are no answers provided by anyone other than yourself.

I feel this keeps the intent of preventing gaming the system for reputation, while removing disincentive from picking the best answer, even if it is your own.

Comment: Not getting 2 points can hardly be called a disincentive.

Comment: Ouch, -4?  I don't see why questions such as this should be disincentivized so severely.  Pleaese help me understand what I have done wrong.

Comment: On the Meta site, a downvote to a feature request generally indicates disagreement with that request. Because highly voted requests are the ones that are looked at to be implemented, downvotes are a way to voice that "I don't think this is a good idea".

Comment: Wow you really like the word disincentive, don't you? :)

Comment: @Peter Agreed - not getting ANY points can hardly be called a disincentive. The amount I've learned from SO is shocking.

Comment: @Bryan Downing I guess it depends upon your personality as to whether it impacts your choice of which answer to accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMHO, self-accepted answers are a feature that should never have been implemented, and definitely don't want to see used more often.

Normally, "acceptance" means *one thing*: the accepted answer was able to help the asker in some way.

But a "self-accept" checkmark on an answer has *no* meaning. Presumably, the user answered their own question because they found the solution on their own - but there's no reason to assume they were able to actually *communicate* that solution in the answer they posted after the fact.

Indeed, I've seen more than a few self-answers that amounted to little more than "the solution described in Bob's answer worked, with some minor tweaks" - indicating that they either should have accepted Bob's answer, or that Bob's answer has one or more critical flaws (the nature of which which shall now remain a mystery to future readers).

To be fair, some users do come back around and post good, detailed answers to their own questions. And that was probably the motivation behind allowing self-accept in the first place. But they don't get any special placement from it, and good answers should get up-voted anyway... so it all just seems rather pointless.

Comment: I don't know about never having been implemented, but I agree that they shouldn't award reputation.  I say the bit about never having been implemented because one of the questions I asked over at Gaming was addressed in a TF2 patch later that same day (which I then pointed out).

Comment: @Powerlord: just to clarify... I'm arguing that adorning your own posts with a green checkmark isn't useful. Posting answers to your own questions is another matter - I definitely agree that they can be useful.

Comment: It's not entirely pointless because self-accepts don't get placed at the top like other accepts.  So if somebody does accept their own answer, if that answer is crap then it won't get any votes and will just stay at the bottom where it should be.  I don't see the harm.

Comment: @Aarobot - By pointless I think Shoq means that it does no harm...... nor good. ---------------------- (... it does affect acceptance rate though)

Comment: It does do good, @Peter, it just doesn't *always* do good.  I've posted a few self-accepts that I know are better than any of the other answers.  Aside from the obvious issue of accept rate, it encourages people to post what *actually* solved the problem, so there's less of a chance that we end up with abandoned questions.  Some people may misuse it, yes, but I really think those people are in the minority.

Comment: @Aarobot: as Peter surmised, I just think it's meaningless - the ranking behavior you describe happens whether or not any self-accept mark was placed. I suppose it might help as a way of removing clutter from the "unanswered" list, but... so will an up-vote. If it can't get *that*, then what indication is there that the answer actually solves *anything*?

Comment: People can't upvote their own answers.  And I suppose you're right, a non-upvoted self-accept doesn't prove much, but the questions most likely to get (legitimate) self accepts are exactly the questions which are least likely to be getting a lot of views - otherwise, the author wouldn't have needed to solve it himself.  Tumbleweed questions are, as far as I know, the primary use case for this feature.

Comment: @Aarobot: right, you can't up-vote your own answers because that would *also* be meaningless - if you didn't think it was good, presumably you wouldn't post it. Voting and (normal) acceptance indicate that *someone* other than the author thought it was worthwhile. Self-acceptance just indicates... an absence of self-loathing?

Comment: @Shog9 - or, it indicates that you continued the research and others didn't, and found the answer yourself. Regarding lack of upvotes: if it's in a niche, then it's entirely possible that it won't attract any votes, where other answers do simply due to initial acitvity. And I just don't get this: "...what indication is there that the answer actually solves anything?" See [my self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665779/compiler-error-when-casting-to-function-pointer) - it's correct. It is the only correct answer. It shows how to solve the problem. Where's the ambiguity?

Comment: @detly: you're missing my point: *of course* **you** think it's correct - otherwise, why would you write it? And I'm not saying it *isn't* - but allowing the author to assert the validity of his own answer doesn't give him anything he didn't already *have*. Heck, you could just start the answer with **"THIS ANSWER IS CORRECT"** in a big, bold font and it would mean just as little as "accepting" it would. It's the difference between getting your research published in a peer-reviewed journal and just [dumping it on a web page somewhere](http://www.timecube.com/)...

Comment: @Shog9 - oh, I'm not arguing I should get rep from it, sure. But I **do** think it should be elevated above the other posts. I mean, in my example there, it **is** correct, but for some reason I can't signify that as I would if someone else sent exactly the same set of emails that I did. The reason no-one has upvoted my answer is because I was probably the only person in the world doing exactly that thing with exactly that build of that particular compiler. Besides, if I'm not qualified to judge my own answer to be correct, why would I be qualified to judge someone else's answer?

Comment: (Love Timecube though... that page freaks me the hell out.)

Comment: @detly: to answer your last question, consider an answer you've provided to someone else's question where, although you did your best, you were unable to communicate to them the information necessary for them to solve the problem. Although the answer was clear in your own mind, you were unable to put this into words the asker could understand... It isn't enough for an answer to signify that *you* know the solution - if someone else can't read and understand it, then it's useless. An up-vote, and especially a normal "accept", provides the reassurance that you've communicated effectively.

Comment: @Shog9 - okay, I see your point.

Comment: Shog9: You of all people should know that accepted answer != correct answer.  Accepted answer means that it was the answer that solved the problem, and self-acceptance is no different.  The author has every right to claim that none of the other solutions were satisfactory and that he came up with his own; naturally, the system recognizes that his solution has not been peer-reviewed by de-prioritizing it in the sort order and eliminating the rep reward (including the +2 that the question author normally receives).  I really don't see the problem.

Comment: @Aarobot: A *normal* accepted answer indicates that it helped the asker solve the problem. A self-accepted answer *didn't exist* when the problem was solved - so the normal meaning cannot possibly apply. So what *does* it mean?

Comment: So you're going to tell me that you've never had to explain how you solved a problem after you solved it?  Come on.  The chronology doesn't matter here.  It's also possible for somebody to *change* their accepted answer - does that also violate the definition, even if the newly-accepted answer is from a different user and came in after the original problem was solved?

Comment: @Aarobot: I've explained my solutions to problems many times, with a number of my explanations appearing as answers on SO. I don't give myself a big, "works on my machine" sticker each time. Again, what does a self-accept say that merely *posting an answer* doesn't? Or look at this another way: should I be able to *up-vote* my own answers, provided I don't get any rep for it? *Who wouldn't?!*

Comment: Accepting is not the same as upvoting.  Upvoting says it's a good answer, which the author can't verify objectively.  Accepting simply says that it solved the problem, which the author *can* verify objectively if it was his question.  I have previously posted my own answers but still accepted someone else's, so that argument is out, and the self-accept says a great deal in tumbleweed questions or questions with only 0-voted answers.  And because it's immune to rep and sorting (which would be very difficult to do with upvotes, by the way), it's not doing any harm.  Again, what's the problem?

Comment: @Aarobot: Actually, the author *can't* verify that objectively. Hindsight being 20/20 and all that, he's biased by having already solved the problem before composing the answer. He's further biased by having *written* the answer. And the *problem* is that it distorts expectations, prompting suggestions like this one. I don't have a problem with you or anyone else answering their own questions. But taking a UI element that *normally* means one thing and making it mean something else... I just don't see the point.

Answer (score 4):

I think the main reason for not giving points for accepting your own answers, is that **you are least able to judge the quality of your own answers** due to personal bias (conscious or unconscious) and just being wrapped up in the whole problem emotionally.

Comment: I'm missing how this would allow gaming the system.  How would I benefit my reputation by preferring my own answer over another under this proposal?

Comment: If you've drafted a question that other people have answered and all you want is to game a measly 2 points of reputation, wouldn't just accepting one of those answers be a lot easier?

Comment: There are easier ways to game the system, but I definitely agree that answerers - even when answering their own questions - are ill-suited judge their own answers.

Comment: @Willam - edited